# what is the difference between this two constructors in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, object, prototypal-inheritance

on MDN's [page for Call](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) there is an example of 3 constructors: Product, Food, and Toy

```
function Product(name, price) {
    this.name = name;
    this.price = price;

    if (price < 0)
        throw RangeError('Cannot create product "' + name + '" with a negative price');
    return this;
}

function Food(name, price) {
    Product.call(this, name, price);
    this.category = 'food';
}
Food.prototype = Object.create(Product.prototype);
```

Why is this line necessary?

```
Food.prototype = Object.create(Product.prototype);
```

Can't I just simply do this?

```
function Food (name, price) {
    var me = Product.call(this, name, price);
    me.category = 'food';
    return me;
}
```

Comment: in your "simply" option, post-init changes to Product's prototype won't appear on Food instances. that might be a good thing, depending on your needs. and yes, there's a lot of ways to setup this sort of thing and they all have minor differences. use what works for you.

Comment: @dandavis what you said is true. Can you put that as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One difference is the syntax. In my opinion, it is better in the first snippet.

Basically this :

```
Food.prototype = Object.create(Product.prototype);
```

and later on this

```
Toy.prototype = Object.create(Product.prototype);
```

mean that they share the same prototype of product, which is nice. But in the example you are showing us, they aren't really exploiting the `class` concept which is not really present in JavaScript, but active in must langage (like PHP for example).

You could have function or properties attached only to a toy or food :

```
Food.prototype = Object.create(Product.prototype);
Food.prototype.eat = function(){ //Toy object can't call that function
    alert('Om Nom Nom')
}
```

Of course you could do that as well :

```
function Food (name, price) {
    var me = Product.call(this, name, price);
    me.category = 'food';
    me.eat = function(){
        alert('Om Nom Nom');
    };
    return me;
}
```

But that lead to an unneeded memory usage and may affect performance.

Lastly, the use of `instanceof` will be wrong. With the second method, you will be unable to know if you object is a product:

```
//Method1
alert(foodObj instanceof Food); //true
alert(foodObj instanceof Product); //true

//Method2
alert(foodObj instanceof Food); //true
alert(foodObj instanceof Product); //false
```

[Live example](http://jsfiddle.net/Jk43q/)

Comment: +1 for bringing up instanceof. However, I use node.js and try to validate your result. This is what I get:

[code snippet](https://gist.github.com/tholapz/10160289)

Comment: @user3349705 i was half wrong about the instance of thing. With the `simply` you lose the reference to `Product`, not `Food`. As for your example, one of you object is `Food2`, so `instanceof Food` return false, see the fiddle at the end of the answer!

Comment: I see that was my mistake to check instanceof Food instead of Food2. However, what do you mean by the name of the object will be different?

Comment: @user3349705 my answer was long, I kinda lose the track of it. I just meant the name of the different instances.

Answer (score 1):

The difference is that your object `Food` will not inherit the prototype methods of `Product`. It returns what looks like to be an instance of `Product` but there are differences.